# Gnuplot - plot a circle with x-axis as date

Tags: gnuplot

Its some time series stock data I am plotting. I.e. x-axis is date while y is stock price.

My datafile "Cir2.txt" looks like this:

```
2/25/2016,18600,10/23/2008,11000
```

I would like to plot a circle with center at (2/25/2016,18600) and with radius of length that will have the point (10/23/2008,11000) be on the circle itself.

I plot it like this:

```
plot 'Cir2.txt' u 1:2:timecolumn((sqrt((timecolumn($1,"%m/%d/%Y")-timecolumn($3,"%m/%d/%Y"))**2 + ($2-$4)**2))/2) with circles
```

However, the radius plotted seems to be much shorter and it doesn't pass through the point (10/23/2008,11000) as expected. It seems the radius parameter need a very huge number to show something meaningful. And seems that related to the fact that x-axis is a date.

Comment: sorry, I mean this: plot 'Cir2.txt' u 1:2:(sqrt((timecolumn($1,"%m/%d/%Y")-timecolumn($3,"%m/%d/%Y"))**2 + ($2-$4)**2))/2) with circles

Comment: full script below: set title "Hang Seng Gann" font ",20"
set key off
set size ratio -1 1,1
set xdata time 
set timefmt "%m/%d/%Y" 
set xrange ["01/01/1990":"05/29/2017"] noreverse
set format x "%m/%d/%Y"
set mouse mouseformat 3;
set yrange [ 0.00000 : 32000.0000 ] noreverse nowriteback
set xlabel 'Date'
set ylabel 'Price'
set grid
set datafile separator "," 
plot 'HS2.txt' using 1:2:4:3:5 with candlesticks,\
'Cir2.txt' u 1:2:((sqrt((timecolumn($1,"%m/%d/%Y")-timecolumn($3,"%m/%d/%Y"))**2 + ($2-$4)**2))/2) with circles

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit complicated by the fact (as the documentation states) that the radius is in units of the x-axis:

> The `circles` style plots a circle with an explicit radius at each data point.
>    If three columns of data are present, they are interpreted as x, y, radius.
>    The radius is always interpreted in the units of the plot's horizontal axis
>    (x or x2).  The scale on y and the aspect ratio of the plot are both ignored.

As a workaround, one could first generate an empty plot using `p 1/0` to initialize the internal Gnuplot variables (see below), transform the coordinates into dimensionless ones, calculate the radius there, and finally express this radius in the units of the x-axis.

```
customFormat="%m/%d/%Y"

set datafile separator ","
set xdata time
set format x "%m/%Y"
set timefmt customFormat

set xrange ["01/01/1990":"05/29/2017"]
set yrange [0:32000]
set xtics ("10/23/2008" "10/23/2008" 0, "2/25/2016" "2/25/2016" 0)

set xlabel 'Date'
set ylabel 'Price'
set grid

unset key

p 1/0

ex = (GPVAL_X_MAX - GPVAL_X_MIN) / (GPVAL_TERM_XMAX - GPVAL_TERM_XMIN)
ey = (GPVAL_Y_MAX - GPVAL_Y_MIN) / (GPVAL_TERM_YMAX - GPVAL_TERM_YMIN)

fn(x0, x1, y0, y1) = sqrt( ((x1-x0)/ex)**2 + ((y1-y0)/ey)**2 )*ex

p \
    'Cir2.txt' u 1:2 w p lc rgb 'red', \
    '' u 3:4 w p lc rgb 'blue', \
    '' u 1:2:(fn(timecolumn(1, customFormat), timecolumn(3, customFormat), $2, $4)) w circles lc rgb 'black'
```

This then produces:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help ewcz! it works perfectly! really appreciate.

Comment: @ALEUNG my pleasure... :)